# How to send Session ID parameter out FROM Moodle?

Tags: moodle

I need to send user-specific values to an external system **from** Moodle.  How can I force Moodle to send the session ID (or user ID, activity ID, etc.) to this third-party system?  All of the articles out there seem to be written for calling *into* Moodle but this is not what I need to do.

Important:
I cannot alter the Moodle installation.  The solution must only involve editing content.  This means I cannot author a new plugin or alter any of the Moodle source code.

**Edit:**
I do have direct access to the Moodle database from a separate external API.  The goal was to use this connection to validate the incoming parameters.  However, I still need to be able to construct a parameterized URL to call out the external app.  That app would then be able to validate the supplied values against the database.  If the session ID is not available then I would need the values regarding the page, user, module, etc. to be sent via the parameterized URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `session id` do you mean the current user session? There is a session key stored in `$_SESSION['USER']->sesskey` but its not really useful data. It expires when a user logs out.

`$_SESSION` is server side, so you would need to use PHP code which isn't allowed in content for security reasons.

Have you got access to the database? You could pull user id and activity id from there. Otherwise you will need to use an API or a plugin.

EDIT: There is a URL activity that you could use to send data externally. But that would require the user to click the link.

Data includes user and course ids.

https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/URL_resource_settings

I can't think of any solution to send data externally without writing some PHP code or adding a plugin.

You can add javascript to every page via Site administration > Appearance > Additional HTML but the session variables aren't available without PHP.

https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Header_and_footer

Comment: I've edited the original question to add some clarity.  Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Updated the answer, there is the URL activity

Comment: Thanks.  This helps.  The URL also provides the ability to pass in the site URL, static variables (like a token), etc.  This, combined with the user ID and course ID, lets me validate the incoming request against the database and determine what they ultimately need to see.

Comment: On a side note, the URL type you pointed out also has an "embed" capability which causes Moodle to render the output in an IFrame.  Works perfectly.